# 301 redirect not working for home page, possible rewrite rule issue?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have set the 301 redirects for all pages one by one as both the domain and website structure are different.

Using the pattern:
`301 redirect /page https://newdomain.com/new-page`

But I have some issues redirecting the home page, adding `301 redirect / https://newdomain.com` works for the home page but **removes the slash between .com and the rest of the URLs so part of my redirects ends up on something like https://newdomain.comnewpage**. The issue is present only for the pages in the root directory, subdirectories work as supposed.

I assume **the problem might be existing rewrite rules from the old site .htaccess.**

There are two of them (the old site is Laravel), one in www and one inside the public subdirectory.

The first .htaccess has these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://olddomain.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

The second one:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: `301 redirect / https://newdomain.com` - that looks the wrong way around, the `Redirect` directive should come first, and then the optional status code.

Comment: Quote docs: _"Then any request beginning with `URL-path` will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target URL. Additional path information beyond the matched `URL-path` will be appended to the target URL."_ - that's how you lose your slash, because when you request `/foo` and match against `/`, then the _"beyond the matched `URL-path`"_ part is only `foo`- which will get appended to your target URL, `https://newdomain.com`. Make your target URL `https://newdomain.com/`

Comment: Tried that, it works for the home page, but the new site structure doesn't match the old one so most of the content ends up on 404 page.

Comment: A bit better is to use '''RedirectMatch 301 /$ http://newdomain.com/''' but then I have issues with two other pages (/page1 and /page2) which end up with the redirected URL '''olddomain.com/page1https://olddomain/page2''' (both of them exactly the same).

Comment: Does your same .htaccess configuration apply for the new domain as well? If not, you simply need to order your redirects properly, from most to least specific.

Answer (score 0):

> adding `301 redirect / https://newdomain.com` works for the home page but removes the slash between `.com` and the rest of the URLs so part of my redirects ends up on something like `https://newdomain.comnewpage`.

Because you've omitted the slash on the end of the target URL. It should be like this instead:

```
Redirect 301 / https://newdomain.com/
```

This rule also needs to be last, after all your specific redirects since the `Redirect` directive is prefix-matching and everything after the match is copied onto the end of the target URL. The order of these `Redirect` directives is important. The above rule redirects `/foo/bar` to `https://newdomain.com/foo/bar` (`foo/bar` is copied onto the end of the target URL).

On the other hand, if you want to redirect the homepage and nothing else (perhaps you have old URLs that should 404) then use a `RedirectMatch` directive instead, that uses a regex, rather than simple prefix matching. For example:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ https://newdomain.com/
```

NB: You must first test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

---

> I assume the problem might be existing rewrite rules from the old site .htaccess.
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://olddomain.com/$1 [R,L]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
> ```

If you are redirecting everything with mod_alias `Redirect` directives then you should remove your existing mod_rewrite directives, although they aren't the cause of your immediate problem.